# Laquelle de ces phrases contient une faute dans l’emploi du pronom démonstratif ?

Tags: pronoms, démonstratifs

On nous a donnés l'exercice suivant :

> Trouver une faute dans l'emploi du pronom démonstratif,
>
> a)    Vous avez raté le train de sept heures mais vous pouvez prendre
>   celui de huit heures.
>   b)  Laisse cette guitare, c’est celle de mon
>   cousin.
>   c)  Marc, c’est celui-ci dont Lucie nous a parlé en sortant du
>   lycée.
>   d)  Nous avons rencontré nos amis, ceux dont tu apprécies
>   l’humour.

Je sens que quelque chose cloche avec la troisième phrase, mais je ne peux pas la préciser.

<sub>Commençons par la première phrase. L'emploi du pronom démonstratif est correct, car `celui` remplace `le train`. Dans la deuxième, comme le mot `guitare` est féminin, `celle` le remplace correctement. Dans la quatrième, `ceux` se réfère à `amis`.</sub>

Dans la troisième phrase, `celui-ci` doit montrer un objet et `dont` va se rapporter à lui. Je ne vois pas la faute. Que serait-elle ?

Comment: Effectivement si on doit trouver une erreur je pencherais pour la troisième parce qu'elle est ambiguë et  les autres ne le sont pas.

Comment: Cette question démontre un très bon niveau de français et sens de la langue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut comprendre la phrase

> Marc, c’est celui-ci dont Lucie nous a parlé en sortant du lycée.

de deux façons.

Vu la ponctuation (virgule après Marc qui est mis en apposition) il faut comprendre que Marc est la personne dont Lucie nous a parlé en sortant du lycée, c'est à dire que la phrase correcte serait :

- > Marc, c’est celui dont Lucie nous a parlé en sortant du lycée.

le pronom démonstratif **celui** est mis pour Marc.

Le renforcement du pronom démonstratif par la particule **ci** exprime une idée de proximité de lieu ou de temps, elle n'est pas nécessaire dans le cas où Marc est la personne que je désigne. Mais on peut très bien imaginer une situation où on la mettrait. Par exemple si j'oppose Marc à quelqu'un d'autre, j'emploierais **celui-ci** plus volontiers.  Imaginons la conversation suivante :

- > Tiens voici mes deux amis, Marc et Paul.
  >   Marc, c’est celui-ci dont Lucie nous a parlé en sortant du lycée.

l'emploi de celui-ci renforce la précision (Marc et pas Paul). Mais l'emploi de celui-ci ne serait cependant pas obligatoire.

Par contre, dite oralement et avec l'intonation appropriée, et selon le contexte, on pourrait comprendre la phrase de l'exercice ainsi :

- > Marc ! C’est celui-ci dont Lucie nous a parlé en sortant du lycée.

C'est à dire que je m'adresse à une personne qui s'appelle Marc et que j'apostrophe :

- > Marc !

et je lui dis que l'objet que je désigne, représenté par le pronom démonstratif **celui-ci** est celui dont Lucie nous a parlé en sortant du lycée.

- > C’est celui-ci dont Lucie nous a parlé en sortant du lycée.

Le renforcement du pronom démonstratif par la particule **ci** est devenu obligatoire.

Les exercices de grammaire envisagent rarement des différences de contextes, et pourtant le contexte, écrit, oral, situation des locuteurs ont une importance capitale dans la compréhension.

---

Note : Je ne reviens pas sur les 3 autres phrases que la question a très bien expliquées.

Comment: Mais quelle est la difference entre celui et celui-ci dans la phrase (pour être compté comme une faute) ?

Comment: @Veo J'ai apporté quelques précisions dans la réponse. Mais pour dire pourquoi la personne qui a corrigé a dit que c'est une faute il faudrait être dans sa tête, un autre enseignant aurait trouvé le cas limite ou pas compté de faute. En toute logique un exercice de grammaire ne devrait pas comporter de cas ambigus sujets à interprétation

Comment: Merci ! J'ai compris. :)

Answer (score 2):

Comme le dit Laure, c'est assez ambigu selon le contexte. Même pour des francophones, cette question est délicate. Ce qui est certain, c'est que les phrases 1, 2 et 4 sont correctes, et que la 3 sonne un peu bizarrement.

Je pense que l'exercice veut te faire comprendre que la faute est d'écrire « celui-ci » au lieu de « celui ». Le contexte serait donc, par exemple, qu'une personne parle à une autre personne, à propos de plusieurs personnes qu'ils ont rencontrées la veille :

> Paul, c'est celui qui avait une moustache à la soirée d'hier. Marc, c'est celui qui avait un pull rouge, celui dont Lucie nous a parlé en sortant du lycée.

Précisions :

- Le mec = the guy.
- Ce mec = this guy.
- Celui (qui était là hier...) = the one (who was here yesterday...).
- Celui-ci = this one.
- Celui-là = that one.
- J'ai déjà vu ce mec quelque part... = I've already seen this guy somewhere...
- Quel mec ? Celui qui a une voiture rouge ? = Which guy? The one who has got a red car?
- Oui, celui-ci = Yes, this one.

« -ci » sert à insister sur l'objet que tu désignes, comme si tu montrais avec ton doigt :

- Je veux cette glace ! (*montre avec son doigt*)
- Celle-ci, à la fraise ? (*montre avec son doigt*)
- Non ! Celle-ci, au chocolat ! (*montre avec son doigt*)

Remarque que « ci » a la même origine que « ici » (here), donc « celle-ci » peut être traduit par « this one *here* ». Tu peux aussi utiliser « celui-là », « celle-là », « ceux-là » avec « là », qui veut dire « there ».

- Here and there = Ici et là.